# css-loader can not resolve urls generated by file-loader

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, css-loader, css-modules

I have shared components npm package project which exposes components and css file.
Css file is built using webpack and url/file-loader to resolve fonts.
I can successfully build this project and resulting css look like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url(cf871bb3514694d3252ee1d23f71dd6c.woff2);
}
```

The problem is when i try to use this css from another project which uses webpack and css-loader with css-modules turned on (modules:true), css-loader cannot resolve generated url:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cf871bb3514694d3252ee1d23f71dd6c.woff2'
```

If I change url to:

```
url(./cf871bb3514694d3252ee1d23f71dd6c.woff2);
```

Then it works.

Also if I set `modules:false` then everything works even without `./`

So look like css-loader with turned on css-modules wants url paths as a node relative paths with `./`, not just as a file name.

url in source file look like:

```
url('../assets/fonts/Myfont.woff2');
```

Is there a way how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't disable Node.js-style resolution in webpack in general. However, you can use the [`NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) to intervene in module requests and resolve them on the fly like relative paths.

The following webpack config adjustments should do the trick:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  //...
  plugins: [
    // RegEx matches all requests neither starting with a dot nor a slash
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^[^./]/, resource => {
      // Override the original request
      resource.request = path.resolve(resource.context, resource.request)
    })
  ]
};
```